# KML with raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, kml

[image]

I have a kml file which displays correctly in Google Earth but only as a bounding box in QGIS . What can I do to see the associated raster image?

Comment: What do you want to do? Display your KML in QGIS (then, what does your KML file look like)? Display Google satellite imagery in QGIS?

Comment: Somebody created KML files to overlay existing maps of the Korean War and topographic maps of Korea from 1950's. If I view those kml's in Google Earth I can see the maps in the right place. They point to jpeg images, which themselves are not georeferenced. When I import the same kml file in QGIS, I only get to see the bounding box, not the raster image, like in the picture above. In the attribute table I can see the link to the image but I am not able to display it. Here is that particular image.!http://www.koreanwar2.org/kwp2/maps/l751/korean_war_project_smu_353_3000.jpg

Comment: Could you share the KML file (or a piece of it)?

Comment: Here it is. I can use the extend to georeference the image. I thought it would be an easier way.  I have to split the code...part 1         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">

Comment: ... part 2     <GroundOverlay>
 <name>L751 - 6133 I - SINSI-DONG</name>
 <color>c2ffffff</color>
 <Icon>
  <href>http://www.koreanwar2.org/kwp2/maps/l751/korean_war_project_smu_353_3000.jpg</href>
  <viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale>
 </Icon>
 <LatLonBox>
  <north>40.0025</north>
  <south>39.836</south>
  <east>125.001</east>
  <west>124.751</west>
 </LatLonBox>
</GroundOverlay>
</kml>

Comment: I have the same issue with QGIS trying to import RadioMobile generated KML files. Displays correctly in Google Earth but just a bounding box in QGIS. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"> <GroundOverlay><name>antenna_output.png</name><color>88ffffff</color><Icon> <href>antenna_output.png</href> <viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale></Icon><LatLonBox> <north>-40.8442</north> <south>-41.06916</south> <east> 175.7976</east> <west> 175.4998</west> </LatLonBox></GroundOverlay></kml> I've also tried with the full pathname to the png file the KML file.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to provide any requested clarifications.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm trying to import a raster georeferenced in Google Earth and saved as [.kml](https://shh-cloud.gnz.mpg.de/index.php/s/YKdN9S3NM2LTQd3). It loads in the right place, but without the image – it is displayed as a monocolor rectangular.